# Save ROS configurations like "profile" in Matlab

Tags: matlab

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am launching a **main.launch** file. This file is calling several other configuration files of several nodes depending on the task. I know that I can record the data using `rosbag record` when I'm on mission.

Is there a possibility to save all the *configurations* along with rosbag? I am looking for some thing similar as `profile` in Matlab.

Any help is much appreciated. :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192061/save-ros-configurations-like-%22profile%22-in-matlab/) by [AsifA](https://answers.ros.org/users/3497/asifa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2014-09-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use `rosparam dump` to save parameters to a yaml file.
http://wiki.ros.org/rosparam

I use a script to save all parameters right before recording a bag.

```
#!/bin/bash
rosparam dump `date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S`.yaml
rosbag record /topic1 /topic2 /topic3
```

Edit: Removed -u option from date.

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2014-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AsifA](https://answers.ros.org/users/3497/asifa/) on 2014-09-06**:
Great. In order to use local time instead of universal you can remove `-u` from `date` option.